# How to create several class and instance methods in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I am doing this

```
def self.a
  ...
end

def a
  class.a
end
```

But for several method I would have to replicate instance methods.

I was thinking in a module

```
module A
  def a; end
end
```

And then use it in my model like this:

```
extend A
include A
```

But I am not sure where to put it according Rails folder structure, or even if to put module inside my model.

Any advice?

Comment: why not overriding the `method_missing` for the concerned models?

Comment: hmm, I don't get it could, could you an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Opt 1 - Extend Self

If you want to have ***all*** of your instance methods as class methods as well, you can simply use `extend self`

```
class A
  def foo
    ...
  end

  def bar
    ...
  end

  extend self
end
```

This would allow you to call foo as either `A.foo` or `A.new.foo`.

### Opt 2 - Included Module

If you only want ***some*** of your instance methods to be available as class methods, then you should create a module as you proposed.  You could put that module in the `lib/` folder and either require it or add `lib` to your autoload paths.

You can also include the module directly in the class like so:

```
class A
  def not_shared
    ...
  end

  module SharedMethods
    def foo
      ...
    end

    def bar
      ...
    end
  end
 
  extend  SharedMethods
  include SharedMethods
end
```

### Opt 3 - Delegate

If you're using Rails (or just ActiveSupport), you can also make use of the `delegate` method it adds to class/module.

```
class A
  def not_shared
    ...
  end

  def foo
    ...
  end

  def bar
    ...
  end
 
  delegate :foo, :bar, to: 'self.class'
end
```

See here for details:

http://rdoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/Module:delegate

Comment: I know delegate method, but don't understand how could be useful here.

Comment: @juanpastas I added an example of how delegate could be used

Answer (score 2):

You you want to create a module, like `shared_methods.rb`, you'd put the file in the `/lib` directory.

You would include the module like this:

```
class NewClass
  include SharedMethods

  ...

end
```

Comment: This addresses how to share methods between two classes, but the OP asked how to share methods between a class and it's instances.